# Random sampling from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random

I want to generate 2x6 dataframe which represents a Rack.Half of this dataframe are filled with storage items and the  other half is with retrieval items.
I want to do is random chosing half of these 12 items and say that they are storage and others are retrieval.
How can I randomly choose?

I tried random.sample but this chooses random columns.Actually I want to choose random items individually.

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
   0  1  2  3   4   5
0  0  1  2  3   4   5
1  6  7  8  9  10  11
```

You can craft a random numpy array to select/mask half of the values:

```
a = np.repeat([True,False], df.size//2)
np.random.shuffle(a)
a = a.reshape(df.shape)
```

Then select your two groups:

```
df.mask(a)
     0   1    2    3   4     5
0  NaN NaN  NaN  3.0   4   NaN
1  6.0 NaN  8.0  NaN  10  11.0

df.where(a)
     0  1    2    3   4    5
0  0.0  1  2.0  NaN NaN  5.0
1  NaN  7  NaN  9.0 NaN  NaN
```

If you simply want 6 random elements, use `nummy.random.choice`:

```
np.random.choice(df.to_numpy(). ravel(), 6, replace=False)
```

Example:

```
array([ 4,  5, 11,  7,  8,  3])
```

Comment: df.mask and df.where are the exact solutions I've been looking for, thanks a lot. But for the dataframe operations how can I get rid of NaN values?

Comment: @GTek what would you want as output? You can pick any fill value in `mask`/`where`, for example `df.mask(a, -999)`

Comment: I want to calculate index and column distances for each items in df.mask(a) and df.where(a) dataframes.For example 4 is in (0,4) in df.mask(a) and 1 is in (0,1) in df.where(a). index distance= 0-0=0 and column distance=4-1=3. I want to calculate this type of operations for each pair

Comment: Ok, then you can `stack`, this will get rid of the NaNs and you'll get the row/col as MultiIndex

Comment: When I stack, then there is a warning like that Series' object has no attribute 'DataFrame' when I try an operation like:                                                                        
 for r in df.mask(a).index:
    for c in df.mask(a).columns :
        g = dfmask.at[r,c]  
        #dict3 = {  i : [r,c]  }      
        for r2 in df.where(a).index:
            for c2 in df.where(a).columns:
                t = dfwhere.at[r2,c2]
                #dict2 = {  j : [int(r2),int(c2)] }         
                          if r>=r2:
                    VD.at[g,t]= int(r)-int(r2)

Comment: With multindexed Series use `s.loc[(r,c)]`, not `at`